# Issue with div compatibility with textbox

Tags: html, asp.net, textbox

I am having 2 div's inside master div, both div's have a combobox and a textbox, My issue is the second div is not identifying/printing its textbox on to webpage when executed My code for second div is -

```
"<div id="Div2" style="float: right;height:260px;     width:47%;position:absolute; margin-left:500%; margin-right:1%;background-color:lightblue; top: 0px; left: -4400px;" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" Text="Matching Entry from Databank" Width="468px" style="text-align:center"></asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Matching Part No." Style="float: left;margin-left:10px;text-align:center" Width="143px"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDBPartNo" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="221px" Style="float: right;text-align:center" Enabled="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDBPartNo_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
<Items>
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"  />
</Items>

</asp:DropDownList>

<br /><br />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Long Description"></asp:Label>enter code here
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDBDesc" runat="server" Height="142px" Width="454px" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>

</div>"
```

Please help me in finding its resolution

Comment: add your html code & CSS

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: Maybe because it's `-4400px` to the left?

Comment: @VDWWD: "-4400" is the dimension related to div-which is coming fine but my textbox is not getting read. Does this dimension of DIV a problem? if yes, then please specify the reason and how to fix it?.Thnx in advance

Comment: Then what do you mean exactly with `identifying/printing`? If I copy your above snippet I can find `txtDBDesc` in code behind, but not on the page visually since it is outside the viewport due to the CSS.

Comment: that's right, the textbox is not visible on the page on execution. What changes has to be done to make it visible?